# error "Object doesn't support property or method 'has'" in Backbone Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, runtime-error, single-page-application

I started learning Backbone Js and was trying to write code for a basic HelloWorld example given on link http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/1.html but stuck with the error as shown in the Backbone Js file.

My code is,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>hello-backbonejs</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
        <script src="backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="practise.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

**Javascript - Practise.js**

```
(function ($) {
    var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('body'),
        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
           this.render(); 
        },
       render: function () {
            $(this.$el).append("<ul> <li>hello world</li> </ul>");
       }
    });
    var listView = new ListView();
})(jQuery);
```

Getting error on line "if (protoProps && _.has(protoProps, 'constructor')) {" in backbone.js file. :(

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: **1.** The line you mention isn't in the code you include. There is no way to tell from your question which line of *your* code is triggering the error. **2.** What is in `backbone.js`? I presume it's a local copy of the backbone source code, yes? **3.** Can you make a hosted version of your example code? Either on JSFiddle, JSBin etc.?

Comment: I'd recommend `el: 'body'` instead of `el: $('body')` to avoid load timing problems and bad habits. `$(this.$el)` is pointless, just say `this.$el` since `$el` is already a jQuery object. If your tutorial is suggesting things like this then you might want to find a better tutorial.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? If it does then accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a very old `underscore` version - `1.1.6` (current version is `1.6.0`). Backbone uses this library, but `_.has` method was introduces in underscore at `1.3.1` and is absent in `1.1.6`. I think, this caused error. Just use latest `underscore` and error should gone away.

**UPDATE** Also it whould be better to use latest jQuery as well